# Upgrading Xcode 4.3 to 4.5 downloads entire package again

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, upgrade

I am upgrading from Xcode 4.3.2 to 4.5..  When I give Upgrade from the App Store, it downloads the entire 1.6 GB again..

Is there no way to upgrade from inside Xcode itself without downloading the entire Xcode dmg?

I know this was not possible in earlier versions of Xcode.. Is that the case in Xcode 4.3 as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode versions are now one self-contained .app bundle.  I believe this means that you can easily run an older self-contained .app bundle of XCode (i.e. have both available) but the downside is clearly having to download the entire app.  The advantage of the "new way" is that it is far less messy, with the downside clearly being the time required to download.